# GetAsyncKeyState input?

Tags: c++, windows, input, directx

I've been using GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey) for my input in a game. I have two questions?
A.) Is it very efficient or is there something else that handles keyboard input better?
B.) How can I limit the key to be sensed once.
        - I imagine it would be something like

```
// Psuedocode
prevState = currentState
currentKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState
if(currentKeyState(whatever key I want) && !prevKeyState(whatever key I want))

Clear currentKeyState
```

I tried to do something like that and it doesn't really work. Should I use some sort of timing thing? I just would like someone to show me or lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean switch to make sure that if the `KEYDOWN` event is `TRUE` or  has already ocurred then do not treat it as a valid key press etc etc..

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE))
             {
              if(hack)hack = false; // if true set to false
              else hack = true;     //if false set to true
              cout<<"Hack set to: " << hack <<endl;
             }
```

Read this post  : http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=120656